# Calling base methods from member initializer list

Tags: c++, constructor, method-call

Is it safe to call *non-virtual* base methods from member initializer list? And virtual?

Comment: The base class is the first thing that's initiallized in the initializer list, so *yes* to the first part. The second may be a bit subtle.

Comment: @BennyK That is the way the language is specified, I don't know why. The standard does not even say that this limitation applies only to non-static member function, but I suppose this is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not safe** to call **any member function** (virtual or not virtual) before all base have been initialized. Bellow an example given in the standard ([[class.base.init]§16](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.base.init#16)):

```
class A {
public:
  A(int);
};

class B : public A {
  int j;
public:
  int f();
  B() : A(f()),     // undefined behavior: calls member function but base A not yet initialized
  j(f()) { }        // well-defined: bases are all initialized
};

class C {
public:
  C(int);
};

class D : public B, C {
  int i;
public:
  D() : C(f()),     // undefined behavior: calls member function but base C not yet initialized
  i(f()) { }        // well-defined: bases are all initialized
};
```

There are more [subtle cases](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.cdtor#4.sentence-3).

Comment: From your reference, undefined behavior is when you call a member function *before all the mem-initializers for base classes have completed*. This is not necessarily the case in the OP's question. In the example from the standard, the problem is with the `A(f())` part, and not `j(f())`.

Comment: @BennyK OK if you think "safe" is equivalent to "not necessarily unsafe".

Comment: What I'm saying is that (at least according to your reference) this is not necessarily UB, as you claimed in a comment to the OP. Besides, calling a non-virtual function of the base class **is** safe (unless used to initialize said base).

Comment: @BennyK Sorry this is my english, in my native language we use the same word for `can` and `may` and the meaning depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

As I was saying in the comment:

The first thing that is initialized in the initializer list of a derived class is the base class. Explicitly it looks like this:

```
class A{ ... };

class B : public A {
    int x, y;
    B() : A{}, x{...}, y{...} {
        ...
    }
};
```

Therefore, when initiallizing `x` and `y` you can call any **non virtual** method of `A`, as it is already constructed.

The second part of the question doesn't have much to do with `virtual`ness - It is simply a question of whether you can call a member function in the constructor. The answer is *yes, but -* you need to make sure you don't use any uninitialized parts of the object.

e.g.

```
struct Base {
    virtual int f(int i) = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    int x;
    int y;

    virtual int f(int i) override { return i; }

    Derived(int i) : Base{}, x{f(i)}, y{f(x)} {}
};
```

is fine, but writing `... Derived(int i) : Base{}, x{f(y)}, y{f(i)} ...` is not.